# Existance of global extremum

Tags: analysis

I wonder if a matrix of second derivatives is positive definite and symmetric and the necessary condition of existance extremum is satisfy then exist exactly one extremum?

Comment: Are you asking: "Let $U$ be a non-empty open set in $\mathbf{R}^{n}$, and let $f:U \to \mathbf{R}$ be twice continuously-differentiable. If $f$ has a unique critical point $p$ in $U$, and if the Hessian $D^{2}f(p)$ is positive-definite, then $p$ is an absolute minimum of $f$"?

Comment: My problem: If $X=(X_1,X_2,\dots,X_n$ is a sample with a distribution of density $p_\theta(x)=h(x)exp(\sum_{i=1}^k \theta_i T_i(x)_C(\theta))$ if matrix $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \theta_i \partial \theta_j}C(\theta)$ is positive define then maximum likelihood estimato of parametr $\theta$ is solution of $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n T_i(x_j)=\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta_i} C(\theta)$$.

Comment: And i compute the log likelihood function $$\frac{\partial ln L(\theta)}{\partial\theta_i}=\sum_{j=1}^n T_i(x_j)-n \frac{\partial C(\theta)}{\partial \theta_i}$$ compare to zero and $$E_\theta(T_i(X))=\frac{\partial C(\theta)}{\partial \theta_i} $$ and $$\frac{\partial^2C(\theta)}{\partial \theta_i\partial \theta_j}=Cov(T_i,T_j)$$ and with assumption we have that this second matrix is postive definite but i don't know why we know that it is unique solution  http://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/~steffen/teaching/bs2siMT04/si6bw.pdf

Comment: I see; could you please add those details to your question? :)

Comment: Why this system $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^nT_i(x_j)=\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta_i}C(\theta)$$ has a unique solution and log likelihood function has maximum

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if this log likelihood function is a concave function
 ($\frac{\partial^2 ln L(\theta)}{\partial \theta_i \partial \theta_j}= -n \frac{\partial^2 C(\theta)}{\partial \theta_i \partial \theta_j}$ with assumption is negative) and has a maximum then it must be absolute maximum?